# How to seed a new joining table in a Rails API db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, join

I have two classes in my Rails API database, that I have just created a joining table for. I had seeded both classes previously so they have data. Now I would like to seed the joining class with id's from the existing data.

This is what the models look like for the first two classes:

```
class Stakeholder < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_stakeholders
  has_many :projects, through: :project_stakeholders
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_stakeholders
  has_many :stakeholders, through: :project_stakeholders
end
```

This is the model for my joining class:

```
class ProjectStakeholder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :stakeholder
end
```

Now I have two questions:

1. How to populate the joint class with data from the two first classes (project_id and stakeholder_id).
2. How can I check in the Rails console for values in the ProjectStakeholder class?

I have researched and tried different options from Stackoverflow but they don't seem to work. Rails guides do not provide an answer either, from what I have seen. Would be very grateful for some ideas!

Comment: Can you show how you are seeding the two tables?

Comment: You didn't provide any information on where you will get the existing linking information from.  Without that, Vasilisa's answer is as much of a hint as we can give you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign stakeholders to the project after creation

```
Project.first.stakeholders << Stakeholder.limit(5)
Project.second.stakeholders << Stakeholder.limit(5).offset(5)
```

You can check it in console in different ways:

```
Project.first.stakeholders.pluck(:id)
ProjectStakeholder.first
```